# How to use `downloadHandler` for download buttons create inside shiny reactable?

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I created `downloadlinks` inside rows of a `reactable`

I did this for a `DT::datatable()` and a `reactable::reactable()`

I also created the respective `output` `downloadHandler`s using apply on the ids

For the `DT` it works , but for the `reactable` it does not.
Please note that the trick for the `DT` to work as I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57978298/8689932), is the:

```
   options = list(
          # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57978298/8689932
          preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
          drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
        )
```

Can I do something similar for the `reactable`?

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998680/shiny-dynamic-ui-a-loop-around-downloadhandler), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973357/how-to-use-downloadhandler-for-the-download-button-create-inside-shiny-datatable)

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(DT)

mtcars2 <- head(mtcars[1:3], 6)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  helpText("The buttons in this DT table work"),
  DTOutput("tbl_DT"),
  hr(),
  helpText("The buttons in this reactable table do work"),
  reactableOutput("tbl_reactable"),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    downLinks = NULL
  )
  
  observe({
    
    ids <- seq_len(nrow(mtcars2))
    
    rv$downLinks <- sprintf('<a id="down_%s" class="shiny-download-link" href="" target="_blank" download>Download</a>', ids)
    
    # Create Outputs
    lapply(ids, function(id){
      
      output[[paste0("down_", id)]] <- downloadHandler(
        
        filename = function(){
          
          paste0("mtcars-from-button-", id, ".csv")
          
        },
        
        content = function(file){
          
          write.csv(mtcars2, file)
          
        }
      )
    })
    
    
  })
  
  output$tbl_reactable <- renderReactable({
    
      tbl <- mtcars2
      
      tbl$links <- rv$downLinks
      
      reactable(tbl,
        
        columns = list(
          links = colDef(html = TRUE)
        )
      )
    
    
  })
  
  
  
  output$tbl_DT <- renderDT({
    
    tbl <- mtcars2
    
    tbl$links <- rv$downLinks
    
      datatable(tbl,
        escape = FALSE, selection = "none",
        options = list(
          # This is important for the DownloadLink s towork
          # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57978298/8689932
          preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
          drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
        )
      )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around with this a bit, I found a way that involves using the session object's function `registerDownload()` to get an href for each link.

Note that this seems to work in a completely different way than the `DT` code. I don't really know enough to say if there are tradeoffs. To me it looks cleaner, but I may be missing something.

```r
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

mtcars2 <- head(mtcars[1:3], 6)

ui <- fluidPage(
    reactableOutput("tbl_reactable"),
    
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    rv <- reactiveValues(
        downLinks = NULL
    )
    
    observe({
        
        ids <- seq_len(nrow(mtcars2))
        
        # ---- MODIFICATIONS TO MAKE DOWNLOADS WORK IN THIS BLOCK ----
        # Need to add the href to the HTML by using `session$registerDownload`
        rv$downLinks <- sprintf(
            '<a id="down_%s" class="shiny-download-link" href="%s" target="_blank" download>Download</a>', 
            ids,
            vapply(ids, FUN.VALUE = character(1), function(id) {
                # `name` matches id in HTML (and name of output object you
                # used to assign downloadHandler to)
                # `filename` is just like downloadHandler's filename 
                # `contentType` is the same as downloadHandler's 
                # contentType but doesn't have NULL as default
                # `func` is equivalent to downloadHandler's content (a
                # function that takes file as parameter and saves to it)
                session$registerDownload(
                    name = paste0("down_", id), 
                    filename = function() { paste0("mtcars-from-button-", id, ".csv") },
                    contentType = NULL,
                    func = function(file) {
                        write.csv(mtcars2, file)
                    }
                )
            })
        )
        # -------------------------------------------------------------

        
        
    })
    
    output$tbl_reactable <- renderReactable({
        
        tbl <- mtcars2
        
        tbl$links <- rv$downLinks
        
        reactable(tbl,
                  
                  columns = list(
                      links = colDef(html = TRUE)
                  )
        )
        
        
    })
    

    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot. Not sure about the pros or cons with respect to the `DT`, but yes it is clean enough for me. Again, thanks for your time and efforts to provide this solution